# AngularJS - Inserting dynamic HTML content

Tags: html, angularjs, directive

I am generating dynamic HTML and prepending it this way:

```
$scope.prepareContent = function(content, id) {
    $scope.myContent = 
        '<div class="foo" id="' + id + '">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="delete(' + id + ')">Delete this content</a>' +
            content +
        '</div>';
}

divOne = angular.element( document.querySelector('.one') );
divOne.prepend($scope.myContent);
```

1 - I would like to know how can I do this using a directive.

2 - I know that I have to use $compile in order to use the link generated this way. How to do this?

Comment: What do you try to achieve ? I smell a usecase for a native angular directive here (Probably ng-repeat ?). The custom directive may not be the best way to solve this. Add theses informations to have a better help.

Comment: This system is a soccer match narrative where the admin can post content and this content will be inserted in particular DIVs like "regular-time", "penalt", "after-match". To insert the content I am using TinyMCE and I got the correct result, the problem is when I want to insert the link tag and I would like to better organize the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of how you can construct your directive.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("myDirective", function(){
        return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          replace: 'true',
          template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>', //put your html content here..
          scope: {
              param1: "=",            
              param2: "=",            
              param3: "="            
          },
          link: function(scope){
            //how to access passed params..
            console.log(scope.param1);
            console.log(scope.param2);
            console.log(scope.param3);
          }
      };
    })
```

On your html then you can call this directive as..

```
<my-directive param1="paramVal1" param2="paramVal2" param3="paramVal3"></my-directive>
```

Comment: bawun, same problem commented bellow.

Comment: Sergio, I think you can set the contents of each section ("regular-time", "penalt", "after-match") to an json object and just use ng-repeat on the contents.. This way you can make a template static but the contents dynamic

<div ng-repeat="content in contents">
<div id="content.id"><a href="delete(content.id)">Delete this content</a></div> 
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('deleteLink', [function ($timeout, $sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          id: '='
        }
        replace: true, // Replace with the template below
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.delete = function () {
            //Write delete logic here using scope.id
          };
        },
        template: '<div class="foo"><a href="#" ng-click="delete()">Delete this content</a></div>'
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Usage

```
<delete-link id="pass the id here"></delete-link>
```

Comment: OK ShankarSangoli, the problem is that I can't use `<delete-link id="pass the id here"></delete-link>` because this content will be inserted in different DIVs according to some system logic. Thats why I use append to do it. Is there any way to do it without the html tag?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a native ng-repeat for your needs.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  Regular time
  <div ng-repeat="content in regularTime.contents">
     {{content}}
     <a href="#" ng-click="regularTime.splice($index,1)">Delete this content</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.regularTime = [];
$scope.regularTime.push("Fantastic !");
```

Use one different tab per section you need.

Hope it meets your needs or at least gave you some clues.

Comment: Thanks Okazaki and Bawun, I will try this approach and see what happens.